# Scrape text from site with password

Tags: java, html, web-scraping

I am trying to automate downloading text data from a website.  Before I can access the website's data,I have to input my username and password.  The code I use to scrape the text is listed below.  The problem is I can't figure out how to login to the page and redirect to the location of the data.  I have tried login in through my browser and then running my code through eclipse but I just end up getting data from the log in screen.  I can retireve data from webistes just fine provided I don't have to go through a login.

```
static public void printPageA(String urlString){
    try {
        // Create a URL for the desired page
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        // Read all the text returned by the server
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String str;
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(str);
            // str is one line of text; readLine() strips the newline character(s)
        }
        in.close();             
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use [Apache HTTP Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) library. It will make it easier to make HTTP requests and it takes care of things like cookies. The site probably uses cookies for keeping information about your session, so you need to:

1. Make the same request as when you submit the login form. This is probably a POST request with parameters such as username and password. You can see it in a network monitor of your browser (developer tools).
2. Read the response. It will probably contain a `Set-Cookie` header containing an ID of your session. You have to send this cookie along with all your subsequent requests, otherwise you will get to the login page. If you use the HTTP Client library, it will take care of it, no need to mess with it in your code.
3. Create a request to any page of the web site that requires authentication.